# div corners from an image css

Tags: html, css

I want to make a div that is 960 x 960px with the glow corners.

How do you position this image correctly using css so it appears in the corners?

http://www.halogamertags.com/sprite_glowCorners_62_59.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it can be done.

```
div{
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
}
img{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Changing the height of the div will also affect the dimensions of the glow image. There are other ways of accomplishing a similar effect, but using the image provided this is how it can be done.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/ZRnJf/

Comment: I don't understand. What is the purpose of the image you provided.

Comment: He wants to use it for sprites.

Answer (score 0):

I saved an 1x1 px slice of your glow effect as glow.png.

I do not know what exactly your goal is, but with this code I get the corners, and the content in the middle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
     >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
    <meta name="page-topic" content="CSS, HTML, Tutorialo" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
    <meta name="distribution" content="global" />

    <meta name="keywords" content="Keywords, here" />
    <meta name="description" content="A good listing to vote up" />

        <title>CSS - DEMO</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: gray;">
        <div style="background-image: url('glow.png'); background-repeat: repeat-x; background-position: top; width: 960px; height:960px; margin: 15px;">
        <div style="background-image: url('glow.png'); background-repeat: repeat-x; background-position: bottom; width: 960px; height:960px; ">
        <div style="background-image: url('glow.png'); background-repeat: repeat-y; background-position: left; width: 960px; height:960px; " >
        <div style="background-image: url('glow.png'); background-repeat: repeat-y; background-position: right; width: 960px; height:960px; ">
            <div style="margin: 1px;">
                Hello World
            </div>

        </div></div></div></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Nowadays there are rumors going on for better using HTML5 doctype rather than XHTML, so before just using XHTML better do some research on the (dis)advantages. I think HTML5 is standard.

Comment: thx dude. this is how you get rewarded for help. doctype is obvious to do on processing systems.

Comment: It isn't obvious, and excluding it in examples waste the time of anyone who follows it (and anyone who follows examples of those who followed it).  Fix it and I'll probably remove my downvote of your answer.